# How can I simulate the microphone response of a bullet's reflected shockwave?

Tags: acoustics, guns, gunshot, reflection, gun

I am doing a project on gunshot acoustics and I need to simulate a realistic microphone response of a supersonic bullet for the same. I have to include the shockwave, the muzzle blast and their reflections. I want to know how I can simulate the latter given that I know the location and orientation of the obstruction. I'd also appreciate even if you could direct me to existing literature on the topic. 
Thanks

PS - This is my first ever question on stackexchange sites and this seemed like the right forum to ask. Please let me know if it is not.